# Convert float int in Java

Tags: java, class

I'm new to Java and I don't have a clue how to convert given variable to int. I've done this:

```
public class Ulamek<T> {
    private T licznik;
    private T mianownik;

    public Ulamek(T licznik, T mianownik) {
        this.licznik = licznik;
        this.mianownik = mianownik;
    }
```

And I want variables `licznik` and `mianownik` always to be type of `int` even if I create an object `Ulamek` with float or double. Is there a way to convert them or any other way to do this?
I have to do this with the `<T>` in `public class Ulamek<T>`.

Comment: Then declare them to be of type `int` instead of `T`.

Comment: if i declare them as int the constructor says it requires type of int but it has to be with T because I want it to be possible to give float or double

Comment: And how do you want/expect to convert _some type `T`_ to `int`?

Comment: If i give float like 3.0f i want it to be 3 or if I give double like 3.0 it also should be 3

Comment: And if it's `String`?

Comment: I don't have to do and exception for String, I know that object will be given float, double or int for sure

Comment: You do. But does Java know that given only `T`?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the class non-generic and use method overloading to support instantiating the class with different types.

Example

```
public class Ulamek {
    private int licznik;
    private int mianownik;

    public Ulamek(int licznik, int mianownik) {
        this.licznik = licznik;
        this.mianownik = mianownik;
    }

    public Ulamek(double licznik, double mianownik) {
        this.licznik = (int)licznik;
        this.mianownik = (int)mianownik;
    }
}
```

Comment: As long as your casting doubles, you may as well get rid of the `int` based constructor since the double constructor will handle ints, floats, and doubles.

Comment: Maybe from a purely technical perspective but it would be confusing if a class with int members didn't have a constructor that takes int arguments. Besides I wanted to demonstrate the use of method overloading in case other types are to be supported.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible approach.

```
    public static <T> int value(T v) {
        int k;
        if (v instanceof Double) {
            k = ((Double)v).intValue();
            return k;
        }
        return -1; // error, only valid for positive values of v.
    }
```

You would need to structure this around exception handling if v is any `Number` since any value of `k` you return could not accurately relate an error.

If v is a primitive, then generics won't be involved and just do a simple cast to `int`

```
double f  = 4.;
int i = (int)f;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're aiming to create a method (in this case it's a constructor, but the principle applies to methods in general) that accepts any type of number and then convert those numbers to an integer value and store those.

If:

- you want to allow any numeric type and want to avoid method overloading,
- you accept that the numbers may get truncated, rounded or even overflow to a negative value (for instance when you provide a `long` value that is larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`)
- and you want to avoid having to perform the type conversion when invoking your constructor (therefore having `int`s as an argument may not be an option in your specific case).

You could use an implementation that leverages Java [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) and the fact that these boxed numerical types all extend the [same base class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Number.html): `Number`. Therefore you could write:

```java
public class Ulamek {
    private int licznik;
    private int mianownik;

    public Ulamek(Number licznik, Number mianownik) {
        this.licznik = Objects
                .requireNonNull(licznik, "licznik cannot be null")
                .intValue();
        this.mianownik = Objects
                .requireNonNull(mianownik, "mianownik cannot be null")
                .intValue();
    }
}
```

No need for generic type parameters.

Note that I added an explicit `requireNonNull` there. You didn't specify how to deal with `null` values, also your target data type (`int`) doesn't have a representation for `null`. Therefore the safe thing to assume is that `null` is not acceptable here.

Now you could write:

```java
var a = new Ulamek(42, 43); // int
var b = new Ulamek(42.0, 43.0); // double
var c = new Ulamek(42l, 43l); // long
var d = new Ulamek(new BigDecimal(42.0), new BigDecimal(43.0));
```

Using this approach, adding range checks before assigning the integer values could prove a bit more challenging should you require those.